# How get (Submit Button' name) in next page in PHP?

Tags: php, forms, button, submit

I hope my question is clear and has an answer. This my Submit Button (not real code):

```
while... input type=submit name=$row['ID']
```

when I click the submit button I need to get its name in the next page. How?

I have different submit buttons and I don't know if the user chose the first, second, third, or `x` button.

Comment: use sessions or post in a form to pass the data. How about show your real code?

Comment: if you var_dump $_REQUEST you will see the the information in there.

Comment: After submit the form you can get only data from GET/POST at next page, server has no dealing with the element type of the form.

Comment: i'am sorry to get -1. I have different submit buttons and i don't know user if choose first one or second or third or ... i need to know in the next page .. ok.. if no solution for this problem .. can i use another way to display list?

Answer (score 4):

Based on your comment you actually need to find out if a button was pressed. Check the example below.

Here is a simple form with a username input and three buttons to perform a variety of actions on that username:

```
<form action="next_page.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="myname" />
  <input type="submit" name="get_myname" value="Give my name back" />
  <input type="submit" name="rand_name" value="I will give you some name" />
  <input type="submit" name="color_name" value="Your name as a rainbow" />
</form>
```

Once one of the `submit` buttons is pressed, we go to **next_page.php** and check to see which one it was and perform an action based on that.

```
<?php
  //this is next_page.php
  if (isset($_POST['get_myname']))   {
    //echo user's name to screen

  } elseif ( isset($_POST['rand_name']) )   {
    //echo a random name

  } elseif ( isset($_POST['color_name']) )   {
    //change every letter to a different colour

  } else   {
    //nothing to do here, just nice to have a comment letting you know
  }
?>
```

Comment: thank you mr.MattCan, Your example is true when I know the names of Buttons, but in my problem I don't know the name that came from the database was attributed as the name of the submit button! So what i need? Get name of submited button in next page. thank you again, always :).

Answer (score 2):

If the submit button is part of a form with a value, you can access it in the $_POST or $_GET data array on the following page. If your script doesn't know the name of the submit button, loop through the postdata to find it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of assigning an id to the button name, use query string and submit to `your_script.php?id=$row['ID']`. Then on the next page use `$_GET['id']` to get the button name.

Comment: sorry mr.matino .. i think your solution will help me but can i have example same:   Choose one (1)php book (2)asp book (3)jsp book. when user click at php book go to the next page with id of php book. choice appear as link Or button not another. thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: [matino's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8416831/384638) is more appropriate if it fits your use-case.

If I understand you correctly, you want to get/check the presence of "the_name" after the submission of the following form:

```
<form method="post">
  <input name="the_name" type="submit">
</form>
```

Now, all POST'ed data is available in PHP's `$_POST` superglobal, however PHP has no way of knowing which part of the data is the submit button.

There are two possible ways around this:

- If you already know the name, you can check its existence with `isset($_POST['the_name'])` - this will tell you if the user submitted the form by clicking the `the_name` submit button (however, if the hit `enter`, the variable would not be present).
- If you can change the HTML, you could use subscripting by changing all submit element names to, e.g., `submit[the_name]` - this way you could find the name of the pressed submit button by looking at `array_keys($_POST['submit'])[0]`.

Comment: I was about to post your second solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to change your application design, you can do simply

```
  foreach ($yourids_used_in_prev_page as $id)
  {
    if (isset($_POST[$id])) // or $_GET if your form method="get"
    {
      // and you are get it!
    }
  }
```

It is not a beautiful solution, but may be appropriate for you