# How to determine which button in a single form was clicked

Tags: php, html

I am designing a PhP application for my project and i want to include a "save,save & new, save & close" function in my forms. all of them are submit buttons. how do i determine which one was clicked?

Comment: you can distinct it by its name...

Comment: A straight [**`answer`**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8425337/1003917)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give them different names and then in PHP check which name is set

**HTML**

```
<input type="submit" name="save" value="Save" />
<input type="submit" name="savenew" value="Save & new" />
```

**PHP**

```
if (isset($_POST['save'])) {
  //  save button
} 
elseif(isset($_POST['savenew']))
{
  // save & new
}
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use switch case for this :

```
switch($_POST['name']){
    case 'Save':
        echo "do code here ";
        break;
    case 'Save & new':
        echo "do code here" ;
        break;

}
```